# How to force Postgresql 8.3 string functions to accept non-string data types

Tags: postgresql

There is a [note](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) in 8.3 doc which explain why my company application is broken after I upgraded Postgresql from 8.1 to 8.3.

Is there an easy way of altering 8.3 version to behave like 8.1? For example: now with 8.3 when I pass data type to the substr function as first argument then I get an error. 8.1 version silently converted data value to string value.

The application is too big and implicit conversion wound solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Eisentraut, a PG developer created a SQL script which adds the missing casts. You can get it [here](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html).